# Swift: How do I assign wilDisplayCell to specific custom register cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have two registered cell in my tableViewController, but one has an animation function to it (Show/Hide), so when I register the second cell and bring it to tableview I get an error in `wilDisplayCell` function of tableview, **How can I tell willDisplayCell to apply only the one type of cell?**

**My 2 custom register cells:**
//Register Custom Cells

```
self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NormalPostTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "NormalPostCell")
self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "VideoTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell")
```

**Overriding Function for one cell type:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        (cell as! NormalPostTableViewCell).watchFrameChanges()
}
```

**Error:**

> Could not cast value of type 'app.VideoTableViewCell' (XXXXXX) to
>   'app.NormalPostTableViewCell' (XXXXXX).

**Error Screeshot:**
[image]

**METHOD 2:**

One other method (2) I try was to set the `willDisplayCell cell:` to `NormalPostTableViewCell` like this and removing the `override`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: NormalPostTableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        (cell as NormalPostTableViewCell).watchFrameChanges()
}
```

**And Method 2 lead to this error:**

> Method 'tableView(*:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)' with
>   Objective-C selector 'tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:'
>   conflicts with method
>   'tableView(*:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)' from superclass
>   'UITableViewController' with the same Objective-C selector

**How can i fix this without interfering with other cell and only apply this function to `NormalPostTableViewCell` class?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let postCell = cell as? NormalPostTableViewCell  {
       postCell.watchFrameChanges()
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer solve the error, but the animation is still applying to all cell, do you know why?

Comment: getting error "use of unresolved identifier".. at starting of if statement.. suggest me if any other solutions...